# there is a big difference between providing care to a degree and being subserivent

Tags: phrase-meaning

I don't understand this sentence:

> There is a big difference between providing care to a degree and being
>   subserivent.

I have severe learning disability, severe ADHD (*Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder*).

I tried googling it, I have tried breaking it down: nothing

Comment: Looks like a misspelling of [***subservient***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subservient): very willing or too willing to obey someone else. So according to the quote, it's okay to provide care to a certain extent, but you shouldn't behave as though you were a serf.

Comment: It's impossible to decipher it very well without some hint as to the context.  (And it's not clear what the learning disability has to do with it.)

Answer (score 1):

"Providing care to a degree" implies placing a limit on how far you will go to help the other person.  "Being subservient" means doing whatever they want you to do, i.e. no limit on what you will do.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people feel they are babysitting us. That they should not be at our beck and call, catering to our every whim and fancy.

Some of us have a mental or behavioural condition whereby if we do not ask the question or perform the task now, we will never ever have the opportunity or motivation to do it anytime soon.

To respond towards such behavioural patterns, a companion is torn between the task of providing aid and feeling being subjugated like a servant.

Hence, a companion would remind us - there is a difference between

1. providing care to a reasonable degree and
2. beyond which I am treated subservient